# Comparing variables in shell scripts

Tags: shell, scripting, sh, ksh, solaris-10

I have got a project that involves shell scripts and comparing values/variables within them.  I have looked here and elsewhere on comparing variables and I have tried all the various examples given but I am running into something that is not as advertised. OS is Solaris10

I have created the following script as a learning experience-

```
#!/bin/ksh

stest()
{
if $X = $Y
then echo they're the same
else echo they're notthe same
fi
}


X=a
Y=a

stest

echo completed
```

I keep getting some variation of the following-

using shell sh or ksh-

```
#./test.sh
./test.sh[2]: a:  not found
completed
```

using shell bash-

```
#./test.sh
./test.sh: line 5: a: command not found
completed
```

I have tried enclosing the `if $X = $Y` line in brackets and double brackets and I get back

```
[a:  not found
```

or

```
[[a:  not found
```

If I change the variables X and Y to the numeral "1" I get the same thing-

```
./test.sh[2]: 1:  not found
```

I have tried enclosing things in single quotes, double quotes & backwards quotes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For strings try `if [ $X == $Y ]`   http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 15):

After `if`, you need a shell command, like anywhere else. `$X = $Y` is parsed as a shell command, meaning `$X` is interpreted as a command name (provided that the value of the variable is a single word).

You can use the `[` command (also available as `test`) or the `[[ … ]]` special syntax to compare two variables. Note that you need spaces on the inside of the brackets: the brackets are a separate token in the shell syntax.

```
if [ "$X" = "$Y" ]; then …
```

or

```
if [[ "$X" = "$Y" ]]; then …
```

`[ … ]` works in any shell, `[[ … ]]` only in ksh, bash and zsh.

Note that you need double quotes around the variables¹. If you leave off the quotes, then the variable is split into multiple words and each word is interpreted as a wildcard pattern. This doesn't happen inside `[[ … ]]`, but the right-hand side of `=` is interpreted as a wildcard pattern there too. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions (unless you want the value of the variable to be used as a list of filename matching patterns, rather than as a string).

¹ <sub>Except on `$X` the `[[ … ]]` syntax.</sub>

Comment: [This endorses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318809/how-to-compare-strings-in-ksh) this solution for people who come here seeking an answer, I just don't have ksh to test it. And the spaces are important.

Answer (score 4):

This KornShell (ksh) script should work:

**soExample.ksh**

```
#!/bin/ksh 

#Initialize Variables
X="a"
Y="a"

#Function to create File with Input
#Params: 1}
stest(){
    if [ "${X}" == "${Y}" ]; then
        echo "they're the same"
    else 
        echo "they're not the same"
    fi
}

#-----------
#---Main----
#-----------
echo "Starting: ${PWD}/${0} with Input Parameters: {1: ${1} {2: ${2} {3: ${3}"
stest #function call#
echo "completed"
echo "Exiting: ${PWD}/${0}"
```

**Output :**

```
user@foo:/tmp $ ksh soExample.ksh
Starting: /tmp/soExample.ksh with Input Parameters: {1:  {2:  {3:
they're not the same
completed
Exiting: /tmp/soExample.ksh
```

**ksh version:**

```
user@foo:/tmp $ echo $KSH_VERSION
@(#)MIRBSD KSH R48 2013/08/16
```

Comment: You should double-quote all variable interpolations. If `$X` contains whitespace you will start seeing error messages or, worse yet, user input being run as code.

Comment: @tripleee Good point, code updated. Do you have a reference where it says double-quoteing all variable interpolations is a ksh best practice?

Comment: Nothing specifically for ksh, but it's fairly obvious when you know how the shell works. Unless you specifically require whitespace splitting and wildcard expansion of a variable's value, it needs to be quoted.